# Автоматическая подстановка картинки для категорий товаров в 1С Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

есть сайт более с чем 100.000 товаров, соответственно в каталоге много категорий и подкатегорий, как сделать что бы картинки к категориям подтягивались автоматически из первого товара каждой категории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автоматически никак, такого функционала нет. Можно использовать API, написать скрипт (учитывая количество элементов, обязательно с пошаговой обработкой), который переберет все Ваши категории и установит нужные изображения, предварительно выдернув их из элемента инфоблока категории.

Копать нужно в этом направлении:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/, https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться